# access elements in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I Want to separate the elements from an array of objects in to another array

```
emplist = [

         {
            "empid": "CL4NX1569868029",
            "orgid": "ZARQP1569826662",
            "accid": "95057056798",
            "fstname": "Testname",
            "lastname": "Last",
            "email": "test.mk@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "empid": "HMXEN1569860677",
            "orgid": "ZARQP1569826662",
            "accid": "9505705709",
            "fstname": "Testname1",
            "lastname": "Last",
            "email": "test.mk@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "empid": "UX74A1569908006",
            "orgid": "ZARQP1569826662",
            "accid": "9100",
            "fstname": "abc",
            "lastname": "abc",
            "email": "abc@abc.com"
        },
]
```

I want to separate fstname and lastname like

```
 source = [ "Testname Last" , "Testname1 Last" , "abc abc" ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include the full source code you have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the `emplist` array into another array with first and last names concatenated (here I used [`template literal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but you can just use `+`).

```js
const emplist = [
   {
      "empid": "CL4NX1569868029",
      "orgid": "ZARQP1569826662",
      "accid": "95057056798",
      "fstname": "Testname",
      "lastname": "Last",
      "email": "test.mk@gmail.com"
  },
  {
      "empid": "HMXEN1569860677",
      "orgid": "ZARQP1569826662",
      "accid": "9505705709",
      "fstname": "Testname1",
      "lastname": "Last",
      "email": "test.mk@gmail.com"
  },
  {
      "empid": "UX74A1569908006",
      "orgid": "ZARQP1569826662",
      "accid": "9100",
      "fstname": "abc",
      "lastname": "abc",
      "email": "abc@abc.com"
  },
];
const source = emplist.map((emp) => `${emp.fstname} ${emp.lastname}`);

console.log(source);
```